# Facebook sdk 3.1.1, ios 6, FBNativeDialogs

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6

My app didnt shows FBNativeDialogs when i try to present a share dialog on ios 6!

I am using DEFacebookComposeViewController library, and on ios 4.3, 5.0 and 5.1 its okay, the dialog appears after the app gets the facebooktoken. But on iOS 6 if the app has a facebook token (i mean the app already got it, example the user logged in with facebook) the dialog didnt appear. Only appear if there is no token and then its working. 
And With iOS 6 DEFacebookComposeViewController its not working. FBNativeDialogs returns with error code 7. 
So my question is how to call DEFacebookComposeViewController on iOS 6 or how can i use FBNativeDialogs when already has facebook token.

```
 BOOL displayedNativeDialog = [FBNativeDialogs
 presentShareDialogModallyFrom:self
 initialText:@""
 image:nil
 url:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.google.com"]
 handler:^(FBNativeDialogResult result, NSError *error) {

     // Only show the error if it is not due to the dialog
     // not being supporte, i.e. code = 7, otherwise ignore
     // because our fallback will show the share view controller.
     if (error && [error code] == 7) {
         return;
     }

     NSString *alertText = @"";
     if (error) {
         alertText = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                      @"error: domain = %@, code = %d",
                      error.domain, error.code];
     } else if (result == FBNativeDialogResultSucceeded) {
         alertText = @"Posted successfully.";
     }
     if (![alertText isEqualToString:@""]) {
         // Show the result in an alert
         [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Result"
                                     message:alertText
                                    delegate:self
                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK!"
                           otherButtonTitles:nil]
          show];
     }
 }];

// Fallback, show the view controller that will post using me/feed
if (!displayedNativeDialog)
{
    UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    CGFloat systemVersion = [[device systemVersion] floatValue];
    if (systemVersion > 5.5)
    {
        return;
    }
    DEFacebookComposeViewController *facebookViewComposer = [[DEFacebookComposeViewController alloc] init];
    self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    [facebookViewComposer setInitialText:@""];
    [facebookViewComposer addURL:@"www.google.com"]];

    [facebookViewComposer setCompletionHandler:^(DEFacebookComposeViewControllerResult result) {
        switch (result) {
            case DEFacebookComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                NSLog(@"Facebook Result: Cancelled");
                break;
            case DEFacebookComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                NSLog(@"Facebook Result: Sent");
                break;
        }

        [facebookViewComposer dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }];
    [self presentModalViewController:facebookViewComposer animated:YES];

    [facebookViewComposer release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need set up the Facebook account on the device/simulator (under Settings->Facebook).

more detail:
http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12592898/facebook-sdk-3-1-presentsharedialogmodally-fails/12681352#12681352